# Aggregating over relationship properties between 2 connected nodes in a path and returning a new reationship with aggregated properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 3 nodes Customer,Phone,ID_Card.

below is my cypher query:

```
match p=((ph: Phone {Phone_ID : "3851308.0"})-[r:Customer_Send | Customer_used_ID | Customer_used_Phone *1..5]-(n2)) with p as p UNWIND relationships(p) as aaa return distinct aaa
```

Out of this is a big connected network for Phone_ID 3851308.0 .

All the relationships in path (p) have properties as TXN_KEY, Send_Time,Pay_Time,Amount

Now, what I need is  to find a way to  aggregate on relationship properties between 2 connected nodes in the path(p) and return a new relationship that has those aggregated properties.

For instance let us consider an example:
A customer "1000000000109533119" has used his ID "10165649.0" 4 times for 4 different transactions . So there will be 4 different Customer_used_ID relationships with properties like TXN_KEY,Send_Time,Pay_Time,Amount . What I want though is to return only one single relationship with all the properties aggregated as Count(Txn_Key), Min(Send_time),Min(pay_Time), Sum(Amount).

So , I want to do the same for every 2 connected nodes in path (p).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Cypher query that does the job:

```
MATCH p = (c:Customer {Galactic_ID : "1000000000275162734"}) - [r:Customer_Send|:Customer_used_ID|:Customer_used_Phone*1..5] - ()
WITH distinct(p) as p,[node IN NODES(p) WHERE node:Customer] AS customer_nodes
UNWIND customer_nodes AS c_node 
 MATCH (c_node) - [r1:Customer_at_Agent] - () 
Unwind relationships(p) as rr with r1,rr, Collect(distinct(rr)) +    Collect(distinct(r1)) as r2 with r2 as r2 Unwind r2 as r3
return startnode(r3),endnode(r3),SUM(r3.Amount),MIN(r3.PayTime),MIN(r3.SendTime),COUNT(TXN_KEY)
```